# Error starting selenium: cannot start the driver service

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, windows-server, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to launch a browser using selenium on my computer. There is a code like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"F:\FirefoxPortable"));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

The console window is launched. And then I get an error:

> Cannot start the driver service on `http://localhost:52200/`

I was already looking for the reasons for such an error, but I could not defeat it. Please help me figure out what could be the matter.

Comment: Did you copy geckodriver.exe  to the folder where the Firefox browser is located?

Comment: Assuming `F:\FirefoxPortable` is the location where the Firefox.exe file is located, then I don't feel like the exe location for Firefox is to blame. Unless the exe being located on the F drive (i.e. **not the C drive**) is causing problems. Maybe anti-virus software is shutting it down? Maybe something is blocking port 52200 on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"F:\FirefoxPortable")
```

1. check if this path exist on your local machine, if not use

```cs
string path = @"F:\FirefoxPortable";
  if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                return;
            }

            // Try to create the directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

2. check if port is being used by other process
   https://www.alphr.com/how-to-check-which-ports-open-windows-10-pc/

Comment: ```csharp
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```
This already checks if exist, if not creates the directory